# Force install Windows XP SP3 on Windows server 2003 R2

Tags: windows

Is it possible to force install Service Pack 3 (for Windows XP) on Windows server 2003 R2 SP2? How to do that?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: No. It is not possible, and it does not conceptually make much sense. Is there any particular reason you want/need to do this?

Comment: You can't install a a patch designed for Windows XP on any other version of Windows.  What you want is not possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. A service pack quite literally is designed to roll up updates for a *specific version of windows*. One does not simply install a service pack for one version of windows on the other.

*Assuming you are an admin*, its worth checking if the program will run in compatibility mode. I don't have a system to check if SP3 is explicitly supported, but it seems XP is supported to some extent according to [MS's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324265/how-to-use-compatibility-mode-technology-in-windows-server-2003)